# install rosjava error

Tags: ros, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I have troubles installing rosjava_core.**

- hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava rosjava_core
  (this ran fine)
- ./gradlew gives me this error:

Building > :rosjava_actionlib:compileJava > Resolving dependencies ':rosjava_a:rosjava_actionlib:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':rosjava_actionlib:compile'.

> Could not find group:ros, module:message.actionlib_msgs, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
> Required by:
> ros.rosjava_core:rosjava_actionlib:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT

**Then I tried this tutorial: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html**

- sudo apt-get install python-setuptools (ran fine)
- easy_install --prefix ~/.local -U rosinstall

error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/katrijne/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-4763.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/home/katrijne/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).

- export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
- ... (see the tutorial)
- easy_install --prefix ~/.local -U pygments (gives the same error as the previous easy_install)
- roscd rosjava_core
- ./gradlew install

21:02:09.331 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
21:02:09.331 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
21:02:09.331 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
21:02:09.332 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':rosjava_messages:generateSources'.
21:02:09.334 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.
21:02:09.335 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
21:02:09.335 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
21:02:09.336 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':rosjava_messages:generateSources'.

**Can you help me?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32416/install-rosjava-error/) by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation for installing rosjava_core has been recently updated to use pip. Please follow the directions as described there (using rosws and pip).

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0